# How to update Parent Component data from Child Component without two way data binding in angular 1.5.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, angularjs-1.5

Sorry if it's a silly question but i am a noob in angular 1.5.x

I am using es6 class based components with one way data bindings throughout the app(best practices as far as i know).

I have a **Container Component**.
It has a **Sidebar Component** and a **Content Component**.

I fetch the **menu options** (array or object) in **Container Component** and pass it to **Sidebar Component** and **Content Component** using **one way** data binding as attributes.

I want to **update the Container Component** whenever i change menu options in **Sidebar Component** or **Content Component** and it should be reflected in both the child components.

I don't seem to find a way ( without two way data binding ) to do it in **angular 1.5** without using $scope events or Service.

Comment: To update a value in a parent component, you can pass in a method (that is defined in the parent, takes in data, and updates parent's values) to the child via & binding. Then call the method in the child, with input data. The input data from the child ends up in the parent's method and updates the values in the parent.

Comment: is it a good approach ? if i have 10 such child components the data will get out of control . But i found another approach which was to make a singleton class and pass it to both parent and child.

Comment: I don't know all the details of your application. That said the approach of passing in a method from the parent is the recommended architectural solution by Angular experts, I have used it in projects with many repeat elements and the data does not get out of control. Your singleton solution does solve the immediate problem, yet not in the recommended way. Your component is now tightly tied to this injected object instead of being dumb and blindly calling an update() its given.

Comment: Thanks for the wise advise i can see why would someone prefer calling a parent's method i will implement that.