# How to update Parent component about the data that child component modified(angular 1.5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, angularjs-1.5

we are having below design in our application.

```
<parent component>
  <child1 component>
  </child1 component>

  <child2 component ng-if="child1 is completed">
  </child2 component>

  <child3 component ng-if="child2 is completed">
  </child3 component>

  <child4 component ng-if="child3 is completed">
  </child4 component>
  <button type=submit>
</parent component>
```

we have data object defined in parent controller called 'AppData' that will have nested data objects by the time user reaches end of the transaction.those nested objects will be formed in child components. in above example child1 and child 2 has only one event thta user can modify so i'm firing chnage even to NGRedux store and updating the 'AppData' with the modified info but where as child 3 has around 20 input's and i cant dispatch events every time one of the 20 fields is modified so how can i displatch event to ngredux store saying step 3 is completed or how can i update parent controller with child 3 data.

i believe we can update the data if we use two way binding but i believe it is not recommended.

what is the best way to achieve above??
 I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058427/how-to-update-parent-component-data-from-child-component-without-two-way-data-bi) but couldn't see any answers.

Comment: You can also use callback (& binding) on-complete on your components that will update AppData variables direclty used in your ngIfs

Comment: @JulienTASSIN Hi Julien, is that(on-complete) is a any event?? i do not know when to fire that & binding as i have 20 fields. but basically i will have to fire when user is moving to different component or something..

Comment: no you will have to code it. If you provider a plunkr or jsfiddle, I can show you.